# Truffle Develop Error

Tags: truffle, truffle-develop

When trying to run truffle develop I get the following access denied error and I'm wondering how to fix this issue. Thank you so much in advance.

```
(base) xxx@xxx-MacBook-Pro smart-contract-30 % ls
contracts       migrations      test            truffle-config.js
(base) xxx@xxx-MacBook-Pro smart-contract-30 % truffle develop
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/anthibn/Library/Preferences/truffle-nodejs/config.json.tmp-5705556743ca3d9c'
    at openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at attempt (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/atomically/dist/utils/retryify.js:33:1)
    at Object.writeFileSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/atomically/dist/index.js:136:1)
    at Conf._write (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/conf/dist/source/index.js:373:1)
    at Conf.set store [as store] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/conf/dist/source/index.js:295:1)
    at Conf.set (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/conf/dist/source/index.js:188:1)
    at Object.getOrGenerateMnemonic (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/mnemonics/mnemonic.js:27:1)
    at Object.getAccountsInfo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/mnemonics/mnemonic.js:41:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/develop/run.js:30:44)
    at Command.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:189:1)
Truffle v5.4.32 (core: 5.4.32)
Node v16.14.0
(base) xxx@xxx-MacBook-Pro smart-contract-30 %
```

Comment: You're getting a permissions error. It looks like you installed truffle globally. I'd suggest installing everything locally so that the truffle files end up in the `node_modules` folder in your project folder instead of in `/Users/anthibn/Library/Preferences/`

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this problem is to uninstall npm and then reinstall it through [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash    
nvm install v16.14.2
nvm current 
npm -v
npm install -g truffle
```

Afterwards, if the error still persists you should:

```
cd  /Users/<yourUser>/Library/Preferences/ 
sudo mv truffle-nodejs/ truffle-nodejs.bk
```